# View all link within <h1></h1>, need to set style on it, to make link small

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make the "view all" link to the right of each h1 header to be smaller.

```
.view-all a:link,
.view-all a:visited {
    text-size:.5em;
}

<h1>Student Activities <span class="view-all">
<a href="/student_activities/calendar/" title="view all">
view all</a></span></h1>
```

Any help is appreciated as to what I am doing wrong.

All of this is within `<div class="content-body"></div>`

If there is a better way of doing this, let me know.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try font-size instead.

Comment: I should of caught that, the brain is moving slow this morning.

Answer (score 3):

The property is font-size, not text-size.

Answer (score 1):

```
.view-all a:link,
.view-all a:visited {
    font-size:.5em;
}

<h1>Student Activities <span class="view-all">
<a href="/student_activities/calendar/" title="view all">
view all</a></span></h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

6 of 1, 1/2 dozen on the other I suppose -- but you could fake the `<h1>` tag with a `<span>` and then put the link next to it in its own `<span>`

```
.veiew-all 
{
 font-size:18pt;
}
<div class="content-body">
    <span class="view-all">Sutdent activities</span>
    <a class="link" href="/student_activities/calendar">view all</a>
</div>
```

somehow this seems cleaner to me.  if it sucks, someone tell me why.

Comment: Well you lose the semantic meaning of the headings, making search engines give less weight to them, which isn't ideal. Also ‘pt’ is never a good unit to use in a screen stylesheet.